# TypeError when using Google Sign In with Capacitor 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I want to implement Google Sign In on my Ionic 5 Angular 12 with Capacitor 3 project.

I am getting a type error.

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'grantOfflineAccess')
```

This is my button

```
 <ion-button size="small" expand="block" color="google" (click)="loginGoogle()">
```

ts function (checkGoogle() function is to call the API.)

```
 import { GoogleAuth } from '@codetrix-studio/capacitor-google-auth';


 async checkGoogle(login_data) {
const loader = await this.loadingCtrl.create({
  spinner: 'bubbles',
});
loader.present();
this.userData.googleLogin(login_data).pipe(
  map((data: any) => {
    loader.dismiss();
    if (data.success) {
      this.userData.setSession('HAS_LOGGED_IN', true);
      this.userData.setUserData(data.userData);
      //this.events.publish('user:signup');
      this.router.navigate(["app/tablinks/home"]);
    }
    else {
     
    }
  },
    err => {
      loader.dismiss();
      
    })
  ).subscribe()
}

  async loginGoogle() {
    console.log('loginGoogle');
    const googleUser = await GoogleAuth.signIn();
    this.checkGoogle(googleUser);
  }
```

Anyone know what that error is? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You probably solved it a different way by now, but one should call `GoogleAuth.initialize` before using `GoogleAuth.signIn`.

From [the docs](https://github.com/CodetrixStudio/CapacitorGoogleAuth#user-content-usage):

> Register plugin and manually initialize
>
> ```js
> import { GoogleAuth } from '@codetrix-studio/capacitor-google-auth';
>
> // use hook after platform dom ready
> GoogleAuth.initialize({
>   clientId: 'CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
>   scopes: ['profile', 'email'],
>   grantOfflineAccess: true,
> });
> ```